# How to tell Intellij NOT to use WSL?

Tags: intellij-idea

i am using windows 10, have installed intellij community edition today to develop maven / java.

The trouble is: intellij tries to use wsl and the java 11 environment installed on wsl.

But i want to use the OpenJDK 17, installed on windows.

The JAVA_HOME environment variable is set, also my PATH includes the java bin folder.

The symptoms when opening the "Hello and welcome!" demo app were:

- "intellij preparing wsl..." is seen, message does not disappear (waited 15+ min)
- Start button is disabled
- when trying to run the program, using shift F10, the app hangs, a popup is shown: "ESC to cancel (min:sec)" But the popup will not disappear, using the ESC key.

I then telled the windows defender to ignore the fsnotifier-wsl and idea64.exe processes as mentioned in this post: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8995

Restarting the IDE now has the start button enabled, clicking it will lead to this error:

Abnormal build process termination:
C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe --distribution Ubuntu-22.04 --exec /bin/bash -l -c "cd ...."

(omitted the rest of the log, since SO thinks "his looks like spam"

At this point I realized the the IDE is trying to use WSL.

As I am using docker, i cannot shutdown WSL.

Is it possible to use IntelliJ on a windows system, ignoring the running WSL?

Comment: Hello! Do I understand correctly that only the JDK set up for the project is located inside WSL? You can change it in the `File | Project Structure... | Project | SDK`; is there any difference?

Comment: I just installed IJ. Th project is the only one in IJ. There is no relation between the project and wsl. It just happens that on my system is a wsl installation and inside this, a old java 9 installation. All of this should be completely ignored.
I finally managed to manually override this odd behavior by your suggestion.
Maybe someone knows the reason why IJ is using WSL / some outdated Java installation, instead of using the more obvious Java installation with JAVA_HOME and PATH.

Comment: Try to select `Help | Find Action` from the main menu, type `Registry...`, select it and in the opened list, find and disable the `wsl.p9.support` and `wsl.p9.show.roots.in.file.chooser` options there to disable the WSL support in IDEA to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

use File / Project Structure to add the proper SDK for the project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).